# How to approach determining time/space complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am trying to understand the time and space complexity of this method.
I read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298938/space-complexity-of-recursive-function) which attempts to explain recursive time/space complexity.
Inspite of that I am still not sure how I would start determining the space and time complexity of this problem.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> fresult;
void findSum(int index,int target, std::vector<int> originals,std::vector<int>  possiblities)
{
    if (index == originals.size())
    {
        //Check if the target has been met
        if (target == 0)
        {
            fresult.push_back(possiblities);
        }
        return;
    }
    
    if (originals[index] <= target)
    {
        possiblities.push_back(a);
        findSum(index, target - originals[index], originals, possiblities);
        possiblities.pop_back();
    }
    findSum(++index, target, originals, possiblities);
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can determine time/space complexity of this problem

Comment: See if you can use this in addition to answers below: https://visualgo.net/en/recursion

Comment: This is particularly for recursion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation