# Need to determine space and time complexity for my code

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, logarithm, space-complexity

I have the following code for calculating x^n:

```
def power(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return x

    d = n//2
   
    return power(x, d) * power(x, n-d)
```

I want to determine the space and time complexity for this code.

**time complexity:** (my analysis)

1. At each level x the function calls itself 2^x times.
2. Since we are dividing n by 2 at each level, there will be logn levels (logn+1 in case n is odd) (log is of base 2)
3. So, total number of function calls will be 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^logn.
4. Each function call will do some k constant work.

I don't know how to simplify this to determine big O.

**space complexity**: (my analysis)

1. At max, there will be logn + 1(in case of odd n) function calls in stack at a given time.
2. So, space complexity will be O(logn).

Need help in determining the time complexity and verifying space complexity.

Comment: "At each level x the function calls itself 2^x times." - no, x does not appear in any complexity analysis, only n.

Comment: time is O(n), space is O(logn)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298938/space-complexity-of-recursive-function

Comment: What do you mean by 2^x ??

Comment: "total number of function calls will be..." Try writing this number in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Let P(n) the number of multiplies involved in the call Power(x, n).

For n a power of 2, let 2^m, we have the simple recurrence P(2^m) = 2 P(2^(m-1)) with P(2) = 1.

Hence the solution P(2^m) = 2^(m-1) or P(n) = n/2.

Answer (score 0):

The number of multiplications is the same as the space complexity in O(log n), **but** a multiplication itself is **not** in O(n') or O(1) (as long as number bit-sizes are not limited by a constant), for n' being the integer bit-size. The school-method for example is of $O(n'^2)$ --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

The algorithm you are mentioning is kind of the Exponentiation by squaring, here you can find more detailed answers about the running time:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: "The number of multiplications is the same as the space complexity" Really? If n = 2: 1 multiplication.  If n = 4: 3 multiplications. If n = 8: 7 multiplications. If n = 16: 15 multiplications. Doesn't look much like a log to me.

Comment: Ah yes your are right