# Why is allConstruct() here considered O(m) space complexity

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

Preface: This implementation was source from the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk

The question is regarding the space complexity of the following function:

target: string
wordBank: array of strings

sample call: allConstruct('purple', ['purp', 'p', 'ur', 'le', 'purpl']))

Code Implementation

```
const allConstruct = (target, wordBank) => {
  for (let word of wordBank) {
    if (target.indexOf(word) === 0) {
      const suffix = target.slice(word.length);
      const suffixWays = allConstruct(suffix, wordBank);
      const targetWays = suffix.map(way => [ word, ...way ]);
      result.push(...targetWays);
    }
  }
}
```

According to the video, space complexity is

> O(M) | M = target.length

This makes sense, because assuming worst case where the string requires M characters to construct the target string, it will have M stack frames

However, why are we not considering the additional space generated by

```
const suffix = target.slice(word.length);
```

Where in each recursive call, we are storing potentially a M length string in memory and

```
const targetWays = suffix.map(way => [ word, ...way ]);
```

Where in each recursive call, we are storing an array of arrays whose size is also not consider within the O(m) space complexity

**Is it because, we just simplify this entirety as the size of the stack frame and we say that it is**

`O(m) | m = number of stack frames per recursion call`

**If the above is the case, then why is it in the video's previous example, countConstruct:**

```
const countConstruct = (target, wordBank) => {
  if (target === '') return 1;
  let totalCount = 0;

  for (let word of wordBank) {
    if (target.indexOf(word) === 0) {
      const numWaysForRest = countConstruct(target.slice(word.length), wordBank);
      totalCount += numWaysForRest;
    }
  }
  return totalCount;
}
```

**Why is this example considered: O(M * M)**

> O(M * M) | M = number of stack frames generated, M = size of suffix stored with each call (target.slice(word.length))

Comment: maybe you should post the expected output so people don't have to visit the yt video

Comment: I see where you are coming from but I don't think output matters in a space complexity problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With help from my friend, we concluded that the YouTube video was just inconsistent.

If we were to frame the variables differently where

> m = the number of stack frames 
> n = the number of characters in substring

then for allConstruct() and countConstruct() space complexity is

O(c * m)

```
c: target.slice(word.length)
m: number of stack frames
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching two other related questions asked that might help you see clearer here.

[Space complexity of recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298938/space-complexity-of-recursive-function)

[How do you find the space complexity of recursive functions such as this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590205/how-do-you-find-the-space-complexity-of-recursive-functions-such-as-this-one)

The way to see if here is as a 'tree' as mentioned in the video you've attached.
What you should be looking at here essentially is how many times the function would be calling itself ( how deep it would go )

```
      const suffixWays = allConstruct(suffix, wordBank);
```

Worst case scenario as you said would be that each word is basically a letter of target. Meaning we would go through that `target.indexOf(word) === 0)` condition `target.length` time ( our M )

This gives us the 'depth' of that tree, and therefor our space complexity.

I am not sure if this really answers the question or if it helps you visualise, feel free to ask more in case, or check the two other posts I've put